# CMake split target_sources in CMakeLists.txt into different targets

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a test project called test_containers. Inside directory there are only cpp files and CMakeLists.txt which looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(test_containers)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME})

target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    test_linear_hash_table.cpp
    test_list.cpp
    test_stack.cpp
    test_string.cpp
    test_vector.cpp
    test_set.cpp
    test_array.cpp
    test_span.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    gtest_main
)

add_test(
    NAME ${PROJECT_NAME}
    COMMAND ${PROJECT_NAME}
)
```

Now the problem is that after build I get only 1 executable bin file called test_containers and it contains all the tests from directory. I want to split this CMakeLists.txt into different targets so that these are different tests. How to do it right?

Comment: "I want to split this CMakeLists.txt into different targets so that these are different tests. How to do it right?" - So you need to **separate** your `.cpp` files for every target you want to create. E.g. `add_executable(test_list test_list.cpp)`, `add_executable(test_stack test_stack.cpp)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your question, as described, you will need to create 1 target per file -- each building the individual source, linking the correct dependencies, and being added as a test.

You might be able to do something like (untested):

```
set(source_files
    test_linear_hash_table.cpp
    test_list.cpp
    test_stack.cpp
    test_string.cpp
    test_vector.cpp
    test_set.cpp
    test_array.cpp
    test_span.cpp
)

# Iterate each source
foreach(source IN LISTS source_files)
  
  # Add the executable + source + dependencies
  add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}.${source})
  target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME}.${source} PRIVATE ${source})
  target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}.${source} PRIVATE gtest_main)

  # Add a test
  add_test(
    NAME ${PROJECT_NAME}.${source}
    COMMAND ${PROJECT_NAME}.${source}
  )
endforeach()
```

(This assumes `${source}` doesn't use any special or invalid characters for target names)

However, generally when people ask this question, it's because they would actually like 1 `CTest` test-case per test in a `GTest` executable. This would allow the CTest dashboard to show each of the different tests independently, which makes scanning for failures quite easy.

If this is what you are looking for, then there's already a module/function that can provide this for you with little effort. You can use the [`GoogleTest`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GoogleTest.html) module with the [`gtest_discover_tests`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GoogleTest.html#command:gtest_discover_tests) function, which will produce 1 CTest test-case per GTest test-case:

```
include(GoogleTest)

gtest_discover_tests(${PROJECT_NAME})
```

Comment: Unknown CMake command "target_like_libraries" must be target_link_libraries

Comment: "No SOURCES given to target: test_containers.PRIVATE" - must be something wrong with variable called source_files

Comment: The first part was obviously a typo. The latter part looks like you have a dot instead of a space between the target name and `PRIVATE` (judging by `test_containers.PRIVATE`). You could always just specify the source directly in `add_executable` as well (e.g. `add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}.${source} ${source})` or something. I was only keeping `target_sources` as that was the approach you were taking

Comment: Remove the `PRIVATE` form the source_files variable.

Comment: @vre Ah, good catch -- I didn't see that got copied over. That's what I get for rushing the answer -- thanks. At any rate, this answer was intended to just be demonstrative of the approach, it's not meant to work for code that is not in front of me and thus is not tested.

Comment: Well, it works but executable files looks like "test_containers.test_array.cpp". Is there some way that bin could be represented in the form "test_array"?

Comment: @a.wise Yes, just compute a target name that works for you by using string commands. You can use other CMake commands to parse the strings to produce names in some structure -- but that's outside the scope of this question.